# Mercurial set per user rights

Tags: configuration, mercurial

I would like to set better user access to my mercurial repos trough the cgi web interface. This is my current hgweb.config :

```
[web]
contact = first.lastname
description = HG Repos
allow_push=user1,user2,user3
allow_read=user1,user2,user3
[paths]
repo01 = /home/mercurial/repo01
repo02 = /home/mercurial/repo02
repo03 = /home/mercurial/repo03
repo04 = /home/mercurial/repo04
```

How to setup the following ? :

- user1 has only access (push/read) to repo01 and repo02
- user2 has only access (read only) to repo01 and repo02
- user3 has only access (read) to repo01 and repo02, (push/read) repo03

I've checked multiple mercurial config tutorials but nothing helped me so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to have the `[web]` section in the `hgweb.config` file. Instead you want to an individual `[web]` config in each repository, using the files

```
/home/mercurial/repo01/.hg/hgrc
/home/mercurial/repo02/.hg/hgrc
etc...
```

Myself I've found the [publishing repositories wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) to be a good tutorial.